# Center a triangle in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a black right-pointing triangle in my div with no luck. The triangle is supposed to function as a button. I want the triangle to look like this inside of a box:

[image: triangle inside box]

Currently, my triangle is to the far left of the box. How do I fix this to center it vertically and horizontally?

**My code:**

```css
.arrow-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 17.3px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
    background-color: #ffcd11;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
    <button class = "arrow-right"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be ( if you already have the arrow inside a container ) . To use position absolute/relative. And position it in the middle of the parent element.

```css
.arrow-right {
 width: 0;
    height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 10px 0 10px 17.3px;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
  background: yellow;
  position:absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  left: calc(50% - 8.65px);
}
.arrow {
  width:200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
   <button class = "arrow-right"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: It works well if we change the width and height of the parent element.

Comment: Thanks.  One question I have now that I've used this is ensuring the button is active if I click anywhere in the yellow box.  Not sure if that would be possible, but I want the ability to have a user click anywhere in that box.

Answer (score 0):

The container needs to be wider than the child which is entirely made of borders.

A little `padding-left` (the same value as your child border width) fixes that.

```css
.arrow-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 17.3px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
  background-color: #ffcd11;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 17.3px;
  background-color: #ffcd11;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <button class="arrow-right"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this, right?

```js
 (function ($) {

  var toggle = $('.arrow-right');

  if (toggle.length) {

   toggle.click(function() {

    var toggleIcon = $('.arrow');
   
    if (toggleIcon.hasClass('open')) {
     toggleIcon.removeClass('open');
    } else {
     toggleIcon.addClass('open');
    }

   });

  }

 })(jQuery);
```

```css
 .arrow-right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
 }

  .arrow {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform-origin: 0% 0%;
   background-image: url('https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
   .arrow.open {
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="arrow-right">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</button>
```

Note: I have swapped the button to be the container thus making the whole block clickable.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution. But it makes the rectangle more larger.

```
.arrow {
   padding:10px; 
   background-color: #ffcd11; 
   width:20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution only add margin for `.arrow-right` and CSS for `.arrow` div:

```css
.arrow-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 17.3px;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
  background-color: #ffcd11;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 17.3px;
  background-color: #ffcd11;
}
```